# Get the source DOM/HTML of an external page from URL

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension

I want to download source code of page from url in Chrome extension.

I have something like this. But don't know how to format text to html.
Or if this formatting works how to display the source code even in console.

```js
fetch('https://www.transfermarkt.com/robert-lewandowski/profil/spieler/38253').then(r => r.text()).then(result => {
  // Result now contains the response text, do what you want...
  console.log("Fetch result: " + result);
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var source_code = parser.parseFromString(result, "text/html");
  console.log("Source code: " + source_code);
});
```

For example I would like to get text from span "dataValue". 
How can I achieve that ?

[image]

Comment: @mplungjan So how to get something from this using getElementByClass or something.

Comment: See my answer....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first console.log below is the textual representation.

The second is the DOM object where you can get stuff to show.

```
fetch('https://www.transfermarkt.com/robert-lewandowski/profil/spieler/38253').then(r => r.text()).then(result => {
  // Result now contains the response text, do what you want...
  // console.log("Source code: " + result); // textual representation
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var DomObject = parser.parseFromString(result, "text/html");
  console.log("Name: " + DomObject.querySelector("title").textContent);
  [...DomObject.querySelectorAll(".dataItem")].forEach(item => {
    if (item.textContent.trim() === "Joined:") {
      console.log("Joined:",item.nextElementSibling.textContent);
    }
  });
})
```

P.S. Don't forget to add the site (or `"<all_urls>"`) in manifest.json:

- ManifestV2: `"permissions": ["*://*.transfermarkt.com/"]`
- ManifestV3: `"host_permissions": ["*://*.transfermarkt.com/"]`

Comment: There is a update with I think more precised question. If You could provide example code how to achieve that I should be able to handle handle the rest.